# How can I get PHP to display the headers it received from a browser?

Tags: php, http, header

Are they all stored in `$_SERVER`? Even custom ones?

Answer (score 44):

Try this

> `print_r`($_SERVER)

It will list everything within the array

Comment: If you want something more specific use : `<?php  print_r($_SERVER[URL])  ?>`

Comment: Does not print `SSL_*` headers, while `getallheaders()` does.

Answer (score 43):

you can use [`getallheaders()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) to get an array of all HTTP headers sent.

```
$headers =  getallheaders();
foreach($headers as $key=>$val){
  echo $key . ': ' . $val . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Every HTTP request header field is in `$_SERVER` (except `Cookie`) and the key begins with `HTTP_`. If you’re using Apache, you can also try [`apache_request_headers`](http://docs.php.net/apache_request_headers).

Comment: Then what about Cookie information? Can we use $_COOKIE[] for fetching them?

Comment: @dskanth Yes, `$_COOKIE` will contain the already parsed cookies sent by the client. But there won’t be a `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']`.

Comment: @Gumbo, How is this diff from `getallheaders`? Are there some headers that are stripped for the latter?

Comment: @Pacerier `getallheaders` is part  of a [server specific extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apache.php), thus it might be available only when using Apache module. On the other hand $_SERVER is always available (working as web-server).

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use [`apache_request_headers()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) or its alias [`getallheaders()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php).

Usage: `echo json_encode(getallheaders());`

If above function does not exist (old PHP or nginx) you can use this as a fallback:

```
<?php 
if (!function_exists('getallheaders')){ 
    function getallheaders() { 
       $headers = ''; 
       foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) { 
            if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') { 
                $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value; 
            } 
       } 
       return $headers; 
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at the [$_SERVER](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable to see what it contains. The linked manual page has a lot of useful information, but also simply do a `var_dump` on it to see what's actually in it. Many of the entries will or won't be filled in, depending on what the client decides to do, and odd quirks of PHP. Looking at the one on my local server, there is also a $_SERVER["ALL_HTTP"] entries that just lists them all as a string, but apparently this isn't standard, as it isn't listed on the manual page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use apache_request_header();
maybe help you.

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();        
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
 echo "<pre>";
 echo "$header : $value";
 echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that http headers' names are rewritten:

1. Prefixed with HTTP_
2. Replaced '-' by '_'
3. Upper Cased

That's at least what I've observed for my custom headers and apache 2.4. This is not canonical nor a comprehensive list of what you should check, but it may lead you to the right direction as for me none of the above helped.