# Sending Custom Header with CURL

Tags: php, xml, curl, http-headers

I want to send a request to a web service via an API as shown below. I have to pass
a custom HTTP header (Hash), I'm using CURL, my code seems to work but I'm not getting
the right response. I'm told it has to do with the hash value, though the value has
been seen to be correct. Is there anything wrong with the way I'm passing it or with
the code itself?

```
 <?php
    $ttime=time();
    $hash="123"."$ttime"."dfryhmn";
    $hash=hash("sha512","$hash");
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Hash:$hash'));      
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://web-service-api.com/getresult.xml?clientid=456&time=$ttime');  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    $xml = curl_exec ($curl);  
     
    if ($xml === false) {
        die('Error fetching data: ' . curl_error($curl));  
    }
    curl_close ($xml);  
    
    echo htmlspecialchars("$xml", ENT_QUOTES);
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`'Hash:$hash'` should be either `"Hash: $hash"` (double quotes) or `'Hash: '.$hash`

The same goes for your URL passed in `CURLOPT_URL`

Comment: Yay! To think it's variable interpolation that has been bugging me.

Answer (score 15):

If you need to get and set custom http headers in php, the following short tutorial is really useful:

**Sending The Request Header**

```
$uri = 'http://localhost/http.php';
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array('X-User: admin', 'X-Authorization: 123456'),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE     => 1
));
$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// echo response output
echo $out;
```

**Reading the custom header**

```
print_r(apache_request_headers());
```

you should see

```
Array
(
    [Host] => localhost
    [Accept] => */*
    [X-User] => admin
    [X-Authorization] => 123456
    [Content-Length] => 9
    [Content-Type] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded
)
```

**Custom Headers with PHP CGI**

in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .? - [E=User:%{HTTP:X-User}, E=Authorization:%{HTTP:X-Authorization}]
```

**Reading the custom headers from $_SERVER**

```
echo $_SERVER['User'];    
echo $_SERVER['Authorization'];
```

**Resources**

- http://www.omaroid.com/php-get-and-set-custom-http-headers/
- [How can I get PHP to display the headers it received from a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403670/how-can-i-get-php-do-display-the-headers-it-recieved-from-a-browser)