# On form submit, get CSRF via php file and pass the value to the request

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I will bounty this question with 50 points when eligible.

I have an upvote system, similar to how voting works here on SO.

When user votes via a `<form>`, I want the submit to first hit 'get-csrf.php' to get a CSRF key, and then pass that value to the request.

How can I achieve this?

jQuery code:

```
jQuery('.votetopicform').submit(ajaxSubmit_votetopicform);

function ajaxSubmit_votetopicform(){

var votetopicform = jQuery(this).serialize();

jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: SiteParameters.site_url+"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: votetopicform,
    success:function(data){
        jQuery(".feedback").html(data); // empty div to show returned data
    }
});

return false;
}
```

In `get-csrf.php`, I have the statement that returns the needed key:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['csrf'])) {
    $_SESSION['csrf'] = substr( md5(rand()), 0, 7);
}

return $_SESSION['csrf'];
```

So, when user clicks submit, I want to get the CSRF via my jQuery code, and then send that to the request and handle it there.

Comment: Why do want this preflight request? Is the standard synchronizer token pattern not good enough? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Synchronizer_token_pattern

Comment: @Halcyon Long story short, all pages are cached (including form) so I need to get the CSRF key via JS instead of simply adding the key directly in the form via html <input>...

Comment: Are you asking how to chain requests?

Comment: @lxalmida Not sure what that terminology means. I am asking: on form submit, I want to hit get-csrf.php, get the returned key, and send it through the form and use that value when I process the form. (my JS knowledge is limited so this should be an easy task for someone who knows)...

Answer (score 2):

The way I would suggest you to do this is putting the token into a hidden input field when delivering the form to the user in the first place.

```
<? if (!isset($_SESSION['csrf'])) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" value="<?= $_SESSION['csrf'] ?>">
<? } ?>
```

If this is not a feasible solution in your case, you could simply chain the requests.

```
jQuery('.votetopicform').submit(ajaxSubmit_requestcsrftoken);

function ajaxSubmit_requestcsrftoken(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: SiteParameters.site_url+"/get-csrf.php",
        success:function(data){
            ajaxSubmit_votetopicform(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Instead of calling `ajaxSubmit_votetopicform` directly on submitting the form, you call a function that requests the csrf-token first. The server returns the token to said function, which calls your function that sends the actual submit and passes the returned token as parameter to it.

In your `ajaxSubmit_votetopicform` - function, you would now only need to add the returned token to the data submitted in the request.

As [$.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) returns a url-encoded string, you would just need to add it to the end of the string:

```
function ajaxSubmit_votetopicform(token){
   var votetopicform = jQuery(this).serialize();
   votetopicform += "&csrftoken=" + token; //token is passed as parameter to this fn

   ....
}
```

So the complete JavaScript - code would look like this:

```
//set the submit - event handler to a function, that requests the token first
jQuery('.votetopicform').submit(ajaxSubmit_requestcsrftoken);

function ajaxSubmit_requestcsrftoken(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: SiteParameters.site_url+"/get-csrf.php",
        success:function(data){
            // after succesfully requesting the CSRF - token, call the function 
            // that should submit the actual form data to your server and pass the token as parameter to it
            // this way you are chaining one request after the other
            ajaxSubmit_votetopicform(data);
        }
    });

    return false; //prevent the form from submitting
}

function ajaxSubmit_votetopicform(token){

    var votetopicform = jQuery(this).serialize();

    //add the token as additional parameter to be sent to the server
    votetopicform += "&csrftoken=" + token;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: SiteParameters.site_url+"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: votetopicform,
        success:function(data){
            jQuery(".feedback").html(data); // empty div to show returned data
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: My JS knowledge is limited so bare with me. Can you please update your answer and add, at the end, the full jQuery code, including my own ajaxSubmit_votetopicform code so I can see how chaining the request would work.

Comment: Good answer. Another option is to include the CSRF token in the request header, but, the hidden form field approach is a common practice.

Comment: @Brett I like that option, you should write up an answer outlining how to include it in the request header.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson added that part. @Brett yes, this seems like a good idea too, `$.ajaxPrefilter` would be a good way to go about this, right?

Comment: @GNi33 Ahh got it, got it. Finally, how do I *get* the token in the PHP function that handles the form?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson sorry, forgot to add the "token" argument in the code-block. you just need to pass it from one function to the other

Comment: @GNi33 Sorry I am still baffled as to how exactly how I *get* the token value in the php function that handles the form? Do you mind elaborating on this so that I can get my head around it please.

Comment: it's a normal parameter that gets passed with the request, like the others, so you will probably access it by something like `$_POST['csrftoken']`

Answer (score 1):

GNi33's answer is a good solution for form submissions, and for use cases like that, I'd recommend his answer. The solution I pose works for forms as well; however, it's more typical for non-form submissions. The idea is that you include the CSRF token in the HTTP request header.

```
jQuery('.votetopicform').submit(ajaxSubmit_votetopicform);

function ajaxSubmit_votetopicform() {
  var votetopicform = jQuery(this).serialize();

  // chain AJAX requests
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: SiteParameters.site_url + "/wp-admin/get-csrf.php"
  }).then(function(token) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: SiteParameters.site_url + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      data: votetopicform,
      headers: {
        "_RequestToken": token
      }
    });
  });

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. However, this is an ajax form, so how would I retrieve the token in the php function that handles the request?

Comment: Excellent, however, how do I get the token in the php function? For example $_POST['lorem']...

Comment: Do a search on how to read all the HTTP header variables in PHP. Try this [example](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403670/how-can-i-get-php-do-display-the-headers-it-recieved-from-a-browser). The name of the token is the name you gave it, in this case `"_RequestToken"`.